# Switch between UserControls in View based on property of ViewModel

Tags: data-binding, mvvm, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

How can I change between UserControls in the View, based on a property of the ViewModel, in a Windows 8 store app?

Say my ViewModel has a property which looks something like this:

```
    class MyViewModel
    {
        public string CurrentStatus
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(CurrentStatusProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CurrentStatusProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentStatusProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentStatus", typeof(string), typeof(MyViewModel), new PropertyMetadata("default", CurrentStatusChanged));


        ...
     }
```

How do I make my View change an UserControl according to the value of the `CurrentStatus`  from the ViewModel?

The strightforward solution for me would have been to create a binding between the `CurrentStatus` from the ViewModel and another string from the View, but apparently data binding can only be used for a `DependencyObject` (which a string isn't).

**Edit**:
The xaml file contains just a `StackPanel` in which I want to put a `UserControl`, based on the CurrentStatus. So, if the `CurrentStatus` is `"one"` I want the `StackPanel` to contain UserControlOne and so on...

Any ideas or nice solutions to this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I usually use a `ContentControl` and set it's `ContentTemplate` based on a `DataTrigger`

I have an example in my blog post [Switching between Views/UserControls using MVVM](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/28/switching-between-viewsusercontrols-using-mvvm/), but here's a sample of what that may look like using your scenario:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultTemplate">
     <local:DefaultUserControl />
</DataTemplate> 

<DataTemplate x:Key="ClosedTemplate">
     <local:ClosedUserControl />
 </DataTemplate>

<Style x:Key="MyContentControlStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource DefaultTemplate}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentStatus}" Value="Closed">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ClosedTemplate}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

...

<ContentControl Style="{StaticResource MyContentControlStyle}" />
```

**EDIT**

Apparently DataTriggers are not supported in WinRT, and have been replaced with the [VisualStateManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.visualstatemanager.aspx). I haven't had the chance to use this yet, however from what I'm reading they used the same approach for WinRT as they did Silverlight (which also didn't support `DataTriggers` until v5), and my solution for Silverlight was to use a [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx)

I hope that can point you in the right direction :)

Comment: I'm sorry, your code does not work in a Windows 8 App project. Visual Studio complains that "Type is not supported in a Windows App project." for `x:Type` and if I fix that it has a problem with `<Style.Triggers>`.

Comment: @alex_and_ra I learn something new every day :) According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7446841/302677), DataTriggers are replaced by the [VisualStateManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.visualstatemanager.aspx) in WinRT

Comment: I never used DataTriggers or the VisualStateManager before.. I'm kind of new at this :) I'm going to give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: @alex_and_ra Sorry I can't be of more help. I haven't worked with Windows 8 or WinRT before. I'd delete my answer, but I think it may be better to leave it to show why this common WPF solution won't work with WinRT. From what I can tell just from reading, triggers are usually done in WinRT with the `VisualStateManager`, the code behind, or a `Converter` like [SteveL suggests](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15139476/302677). Perhaps take another look at his answer to see if it will work. :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I fully understand what you are trying to do. Can you post the xaml?

If what you are wanting is to present the controls differently based on the status, then use a converter and you can present a different template based upon the status:

```
public class StatusToTemplateConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members


    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        switch ((string) value)
        {
            case "Status1":
                return Application.Current.Resources["Status1Template"];
            case "Status2":
                return Application.Current.Resources["Status2Template"];

            default:
                return Application.Current.Resources["Status3Template"];
        }
    }


    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

the above assumes you have your templates defined in a resource file

If all you ae wanting to do is something simpler such as red text for Status1 or Green text for status2 you could have a converter that just converts the status to a colour and bind the FontColor to the status and use the converter.

But like I said, without more code being posted, I'm not 100% clear on what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

While I've used the `DataTemplateSelector` and `IValueConverter` in such cases before - now my favorite approach is using the `VisualStateManager`. I have created a most basic attached property that implements the attached behavior pattern in WinRT XAML Toolkit [here](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/b0ee76bd6492#WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/Extensions/VisualStateExtensions.cs) - that looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Defines an attached property that controls the visual state of the element based on the value.
/// </summary>
public static class VisualStateExtensions
{
    #region State
    /// <summary>
    /// State Attached Dependency Property
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "State",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(VisualStateExtensions),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, OnStateChanged));

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the State property. This dependency property 
    /// indicates the VisualState that the associated control should be set to.
    /// </summary>
    public static string GetState(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return (string)d.GetValue(StateProperty);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the State property. This dependency property 
    /// indicates the VisualState that the associated control should be set to.
    /// </summary>
    public static void SetState(DependencyObject d, string value)
    {
        d.SetValue(StateProperty, value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles changes to the State property.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="d">
    /// The <see cref="DependencyObject"/> on which
    /// the property has changed value.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="e">
    /// Event data that is issued by any event that
    /// tracks changes to the effective value of this property.
    /// </param>
    private static void OnStateChanged(
        DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var stateName = (string)e.NewValue;
        var ctrl = (Control)d;
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(ctrl, stateName, true);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

You should define an enum-style class like the `VisualStates` class in Silverlight Toolkit that lists all your visual states (so you don't have duplicates), e.g.

```
internal static class VisualStates
{
    #region GroupCommon
    /// <summary>
    /// Common state group.
    /// </summary>
    public const string GroupCommon = "CommonStates";

    /// <summary>
    /// Normal state of the Common state group.
    /// </summary>
    public const string StateNormal = "Normal";

    /// <summary>
    /// Normal state of the Common state group.
    /// </summary>
    public const string StateReadOnly = "ReadOnly";

    /// <summary>
    /// MouseOver state of the Common state group.
    /// </summary>
    public const string StateMouseOver = "MouseOver";

    /// <summary>
    /// Pressed state of the Common state group.
    /// </summary>
    public const string StatePressed = "Pressed";

    /// <summary>
    /// Disabled state of the Common state group.
    /// </summary>
    public const string StateDisabled = "Disabled";
    #endregion GroupCommon

    #region GroupFocus
    /// <summary>
    /// Focus state group.
    /// </summary>
    public const string GroupFocus = "FocusStates";

    /// <summary>
    /// Unfocused state of the Focus state group.
    /// </summary>
    public const string StateUnfocused = "Unfocused";

    /// <summary>
    /// Focused state of the Focus state group.
    /// </summary>
    public const string StateFocused = "Focused";
    #endregion GroupFocus
}
```

Once you have these - you can have a property in your view model like

```
public string VisualState { get; set; /* Raise PropertyChange event your preferred way here */ }
```

And in your view say

```
<Page
    ...
    xmlns:extensions="using:WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.Extensions"
    extensions:VisualStateExtensions.State="{Binding VisualState}">...
```

Then your view model can easily drive the change of the visual state and you can use Blend to define what that state looks like - e.g. change the `Content` or `ContentTemplate` or simply visibility of various elements in the layout. I think this method has best support of the designer tools since you can flip between views with a click of a button and make updates to these views in Blend.

Comment: For this line `extensions:VisualStateExtensions.State="{Binding State}">` it says "The attachable property 'State' was not found in type 'VisualStateExtensions'". Also, who should be 'State' from the binding?

Comment: The `VisualStateExtensions` class in my answer has the State property. Just make sure you add `xmlns:extensions="using:WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.Extensions"` to your root XML element in your XAML. Sorry, I missed the State property in the binding should actually be called `VisualState` and it comes from your view model property I quoted in the 3rd code block. Let me update it.