# How to trigger a storyboard on a list item when it is tapped and have the page be notified when the animation ends?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I'm porting a Windows Phone 8 app to Windows 8 and I have a scenario where the user taps an item in my list control / grid view and I want to play an "activation" animation on the item, wait for the animation to complete, and then navigate away from the page.

On Windows Phone, I used DataTriggers in one case, and in another I used VisualTreeHelper to iterate through the view and find the VirtualizingStackPanel and then the actual item and then accessed it directly to invoke the storyboard...

Neither appears to work in this case and also seems that DataTriggers are not supported in winrt ([DataTrigger in WinRT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439532/datatrigger-in-winrt)).

I'd like to do the right thing here. I've seen suggestions that visual states can be used, but it is not clear how in this case.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways I would go about this, though neither is particularly pretty.

### Method A

Create a custom control that will act as each GridView item and place it in the GridView's ItemTemplate.

```
<GridView>
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <mynamespace:MyControl/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

Then, in MyControl's constructor, attach a handler to the Tapped event, and in that handler you can perform your animation. The animation can be defined in MyControl.xaml. MyControl should also expose an event for when the animation is complete

```
public event EventHandler SelectedAnimationComplete;
```

and fire it when your custom storyboard completes.  The page hosting the GridView can attach to MyControl's custom event to perform the navigation.

```
...
<mynamespace:MyControl SelectedAnimationComplete="selectedAnimationComplete"/>
...
```

### Method B

On the GridView, set SelectionMode to None, IsItemClickEnabled to true, and attach a handler to the ItemClick event. Inside the handler, you can use

```
(sender as GridView).ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(e.ClickedItem)
```

to get the GridViewItem, and then dig down the visual tree with VisualTreeHelper.GetChild.  In your ItemTemplate, the root visual (likely a Grid) can have your animation placed in its Resources collection.  Dig down the visual tree until you find the ItemTemplate's root grid, get the animation from its Resources collection, attach a completion handler to it, and run it.  You can perform your navigation in the completion handler.

Comment: Yes! VisualTreeHelper was the answer. The trick was to look for the VariableSizedWrapGrid for the GridView, and then drill down through each of its children to find my custom control. For the ListView (in snapped mode), I was able to just look for the VirtualizingStackPanel as per windows phone 8.