# What is the replacement of Multitrigger in Windwos phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I am working on windows phone 8.1 and i want to use trigger with conditions for starting animation. So is there any replacement for Multitrigger/Multidatatrigger or ConditionBehavior in windows phone 8.1 ?

Comment: There is no MultiTrigger in WP8.1. Can you describe what you are trying to do. Give an example and maybe someone can help solve that problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [DataTrigger with VisualStates in Windows phone 8.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27481555/datatrigger-with-visualstates-in-windows-phone-8-1)