# Winrt, changing a color, depending on a bound value

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have a gridview that looks something like this:

```
<GridView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewItemStyle2}" ItemsSource="{Binding MyMeetingsSquareUsers}" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,10,10,0"  SelectionMode="None" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom">
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" MaximumRowsOrColumns="1"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Height="35" Width="35" Margin="0,0,10,0" >
                <Border BorderBrush="red" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="15">
                    <Ellipse>
                        <Ellipse.Fill>
                            <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="ms-appx:///Images/photo_empty.png"/>
                        </Ellipse.Fill>
                    </Ellipse>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

The `ItemsSource` I use is a list of items of this type:

```
public class MeetingInvitee
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public User user { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage photo { get; set; }
}
```

What I would like to know is, if it is possible to change the color of the Border I use depending on the value in status

For example if I had 3 possible status: `Accepted`, `Rejected`, `Pending`, the colors would be set to either Green, Red or Yellow accordingly.

so if one of the items on the list had a status of Rejected the border would have a red brush

Comment: If you've got the Interactivity/Interactions namespaces you'd just use a combination of DataTriggerBehavior and VisualStateManager like shown in the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439532/datatrigger-in-winrt) which I considered marking as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional templates (instead of style data triggers unfortunately) are the way to go in a store app. What you need to do is define three different templates for each color and in the code behind create a template selector.

### Data Template Selector

```
   public class MeetingTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate AcceptedTemplate { get; set; }

        public DataTemplate RejectedTemplate { get; set; }

        public DataTemplate PendingTemplate { get; set; }

        protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, 
                  DependencyObject container)
        {
           DataTemplate result;

           switch( ((MeetingInvitee) item).Status)
           {
                case "Accepted" : result = AcceptedTemplate; break;
                case "Rejected" : result = RejectedTemplate; break;
                case "Pending"  : result = PendingTemplate; break;
           }

          return result;
        }
    }
```

**Declare Templates in the Resources**

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="AcceptedTemplate">
        <Border Background="Green">
             ...
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="RejectedTemplate">
        <Border Background="Red">
             ...
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PendingTemplate">
        <Border Background="Yellow">
             ...
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>

    <local:MeetingTemplateSelector x:Key="meetingSelector"
                                    AcceptedTemplate="{StaticResource AcceptedTemplate}"
                                    RejectedTemplate="{StaticResource RejectedTemplate}"
                                    PendingTemplate="{StaticResource PendingTemplate}">
    </local:MeetingTemplateSelector >
</UserControl.Resources>
```

**Usage**

```
<GridView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewItemStyle2}" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding MyMeetingsSquareUsers}" 
          ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource meetingSelector}">
```

Comment: @Ric I wish Microsoft would standardize Xaml going forward. I find that that the styling one does on WPF does not work on Silverlight which does not work on Window's store apps.  Maybe with universal apps...that will change.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an implementation of the `IValueConverter` interface and pass that when you bind the `Background` property of your `Border` to your `Status` property of the viewmodel. Example:

```
class StatusValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private static SolidColorBrush _acceptedBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
    private static SolidColorBrush _pendingBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
    private static SolidColorBrush _rejectedBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        SolidColorBrush brush = null;

        if (value != null)
        {
            string status = value.ToString();

            switch (status)
            {
                case "Accepted":
                    brush = _acceptedBrush;
                    break;
                case "Pending":
                    brush = _pendingBrush;
                    break;
                case "Rejected":
                    brush = _rejectedBrush;
                    break;
            }
        }

        if (brush == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Status not valid.");
        }

        return brush;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        // You need this if TwoWay binding mode is used.
    }
}
```

Add the value converter to the page resources (where `local` is the prefix for the namespace in which I defined the `StatusValueConverter`):

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:StatusValueConverter x:Key="StatusConverter" />
</Page.Resources>
```

In your xaml define your `Border` element like this:

```
<Border BorderBrush="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource StatusConverter}}" 
                            BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="15">
                        <Ellipse>
                            <Ellipse.Fill>
                                ...
                            </Ellipse.Fill>
                        </Ellipse>
                    </Border>
```

If you want a completely different visual tree for different values in your view model, then use a `DataTemplateSelector`.